CSS and JavaScript not applying correctly after migrating HTML content to Angular app component due to view encapsulation and script load order issues
I'm currently migrating a static HTML template into an Angular application. The original template works perfectly when placed directly in the index.html file of the Angular project. However, when I move the body content of this template into an Angular component (app.component.html), some of the CSS and JavaScript do not apply correctly, leading to styling and functionality issues.
Issue:
When I replace the <app.component.html> tag with the actual HTML content, everything works fine. But when I use the Angular component to render this content, some styles and JavaScript functionalities do not work as expected.
Request for Help:
I’m looking for insights into why this might be happening and how to properly migrate the content into an Angular component without losing the styling and JavaScript functionality. Any advice on troubleshooting steps or best practices for this kind of migration would be greatly appreciated.
Steps I've Taken:
Checked View Encapsulation: I have already investigated Angular's view encapsulation settings. I tried setting the encapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.None in my component, but the problem persists.
Inspecting Styles: I used browser developer tools to inspect the applied styles. It seems that certain styles are either missing or overridden when the content is moved into the Angular component.
Script Loading Order: I've also checked the order in which the scripts are loaded. All necessary scripts (jQuery, Bootstrap, custom JS files) are included in the index.html and appear to be loading correctly.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately in its current form, the question can't be answered. Please focus to a specific problem. "styling and functionality issues" is not a specific problem. Also, please add a minimal reproducible example of your code, preferably in StackBlitz.

Do you have any scripts referenced under "scripts" part in your angular.json file?

Before, I also faced the same problem that some of the javascript commands I used in the Angular component were not applied correctly, and naturally I used to put these codes in the Oninit cycle, now why was it not applied?
Because, in general, the codes inside the ts file are executed first, then the codes inside the html are made
And when javascript is used for dom, we still don't have dom to access it because Angular component codes are executed first, then html!!
Now, this solution worked for me to put the codes that are related to the dom of the page, which means that the html tags need to be fully loaded, into the ngAfterViewInit cycle.
And this is how my problem was solved
class MyComponent implements Oninit ,AfterViewInit {

  ngOninit() {
    //...
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //...
  }

}

I hope I have helped
